# ubuntu 16.10 uninstalling softwares in ubuntu

Tags: 16.10

I installed 4k video downloader in Ubuntu 16.10 , and I want to uninstall it

its not showing in Ubuntu software centre and I also tried to delete the folder from Ubuntu directory(there is no option to delete)

### how can I uninstall 4k video downloader from my laptop??

Is there any commands to show the list of installed applications in Linux??

Comment: In which way you have installed the program?

Comment: Try this : sudo apt-get remove <application_name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you apparently installed this from a `deb` package not in the software centre, you need to use `dpkg`.

> Is there any commands to show the list of installed applications in
>   Linux??

Yes: `dpkg -l | grep 4k`

To remove completely:

```
dpkg -P <packagename>
```

More on `dpkg` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195794/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-installed-with-dpkg).

Answer (score 0):

Some applications create .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`. Have you checked there?

Also, using the Software Center to delete applications leaves system-wide config files behind. If you want to get rid of those as well, you may want to use:

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```